# Is there a way to have Hugo not generate URLs for each post?

Tags: hugo

This sounds bonkers, but I really do mean than I don't want Hugo to generate URLs.

What I'm trying to achieve is a Google News type site (but much worse). In the front matter of each post I'd record an external URL as a custom variable and spit that out into my template. There'd be no content in each "post" and therefore I don't want to generate a URL nor an entry in a sitemap.

My research tells me I can do the sitemap part by making my own template. Kudos to [Dereck Curren and his guide](https://dereckcurry.com/posts/excluding-pages-from-the-sitemap/).

I can't figure out how I'd stop Hugo from generating a URL entry at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `headless: true` (check official [documentation](https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-bundles/#headless-bundle)).

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Just wanted to say that correct syntax is `headless: true`

Answer (score 1):

This is not bonkers and there are plans to build nolist and norender into Hugo.[*]

For now, the way I do this with my bookmark lists is to have a `layouts/bookmarks/single.html` file that is empty (0 bytes). In `content/bookmarks/whatever.md` I have something like this:

```
---
# draft: true
title: "github.com: Issues · gohugoio/hugo"
link: "https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue"
tag:
  - gohugo
  - bookmark
---
```

Then I use the tag (taxonomy features) of Hugo, along with `.Params.link` to display the links.
This is how I create the the "On other sites" section of my portals, for example my [#gohugo Portal](https://www.ii.com/portal/gohugo/).

[*]: [Add nolist and norender · Issue #6412 · gohugoio/hugo · GitHub](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/6412)

Comment: Ah amazing! Does Hugo still generate a url that's something like `example.com/GitHub-issues-gohugoio`in your example, but you'd have to guess what it is in order to land on the page?